# Expression working with static condition but not working with scope object in html file in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In the below code for Button, I have added ng-disabled condition it is working when I use "qty > 10" but the same condition not working when I add "qty > maxQtySeats" where "maxQtySeats" is my scope variable in which I have assigned value and its printed on html page but not working with condition.

**Following is the code of one of the modal**

```
<div class="rectangleSeats">
            <div style="width: 300px; float: left;">
                <span class="removeSeatstxt" l10n-text="cancellation.removeSeats"></span>
                <br/><br/>
                <span class="opt-box" style="font-size: 12px;" l10n-text="cancellation.seatstoRemove"></span>
            </div>
             <div class="quantity buttons_added" style="float: right;">
                    <form id='myform' ng-app="gemAppSu" ng-controller="ModalInstanceCtrl">
                      <button ng-click="decrement()" class='qtyminus' ng-disabled="qty<=0" style="background-color: transparent;border: none;">
                        <img src="assets/img/minus.svg" width="12px" height="12px"/>
                      </button>
                      <input ng-model="qty" type='text' name='quantity' id='qty' class='qty' style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;
                         border: none;height: 44px;width: 52px;text-align: center;"/>

                      <button ng-click="increment()" style="background-color: transparent;border: none;">
                      <img src="assets/img/plus.svg" width="12px" height="12px"/>
                      </button>
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cancellationbtndiv" >
             <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default nxt-btn" ng-disabled="qty > maxQtySeats">
            <span l10n-text="cancellation.buttonnext"></span></button> 

        </div>
```

**Controller.js**

$scope.maxQtySeats = 0;
 $scope.maxQtySeats = $scope.activeItem.lineItem.totalQuantity;

Comment: Post all the relevant code. Where and how is maxQtySeats defined?

Comment: @JBNizet Added. And I have printed that parameter in html file so I got the value but its not working with expression.

Comment: Does it work if you set `$scope.maxQtySeats` in controller to a static value? E.g `$scope.maxQtySeats = 10;` It seems that you set the value only once and too early and it's undefined at this moment.

Comment: @vrdrv I have printed that value in same html page and it is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution...

It was a problem of parseInt(), After parseInt($scope.activeItem.lineItem.totalQuantity) it is wokring fine.

Thanks.